# Suppose that a mountain has the shape of an elliptic paraboloid $z = c - ax^2 - by^2$

Tags: calculus, vectors

Suppose that a mountain has the shape of an elliptic paraboloid $z = c - ax^2 - by^2$, where $a, b,$ and $c$ are positive constants, $x$, and $y$ are the east-west and north-south map coordinates, and $z$ is the altitude above sea level.

An engineer wishes to build a railroad up the mountain. Straight up the mountain is too steep. At the point $(1,1)$, in what directions may the track be laid out so that it will be climbing with a $3\%$ grade- that is, an angle whose tangent is $0.03$? Note that there are two possibilities.

Where i'm at:

I know that the directional derivative is the slope of the tangent line to the curve of intersection to a surface. So:

Gradient = $\langle f_x, f_y\rangle$

$=\langle-2ax, -2by\rangle $

Gradient at $(1,1) = \langle -2a, -2b\rangle$

Unit vector $= \langle \cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)\rangle$

Directional derivative $= -2a\cdot \cos(\theta) - 2b\cdot \sin(\theta)$

It says that the grade is the angle whose tangent is 0.003

$-2a\cdot \cos(\theta) - 2b\cdot \sin(\theta) = 0.003$

$a\cdot \cos(\theta) + b\cdot \sin(\theta) = -(0.003/2)$

Is this right so far? I'm not sure how to solve for theta.

thanks

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: Did you edit it? Everything seems to look formatted now?

Comment: It was edited by M.Mass.